# Use a ipsec tunnel with a vpn

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec

The company I work for has a ipsec tunnel to another site that we use to have access to various tools. The vpn and ipsec is set up on a Ubuntu server. All of the tools are accessed through a web browser. All of these work while onsite but people need to use the tools through the vpn this used to work but doesn't any more. When trying to access the websites they act just like there is no website there. I don't know that much of what is going on I am a new sys admin so where could I look for problems. I don't really know where to start on this.

I have the vpn started and connect before trying to access the sites. I am able to use ssh and some of the tools work but others don't. Some of the sites just don't load but there are a few that give a 502 Bad Gateway - Response Error, a bad response was received from another proxy server or the destination origin server

Comment: is there any setting that openvpn has that could cause this problem

Answer (score 3):

Are you logging into the VPN BEFORE you try to access these sites?

Comment: I have the vpn started and connect before trying to access the sites

Comment: Just making sure, a lot of times that can be easily overlooked.  I meant to make that a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happened is you need to set the clients who are logging into the VPN to use your local DNS. They are likely looking for an website that's not routed externally (intranets) and as such external DNS senders cannot resolve their requests.

Has your DNS changed recently?

What you can do is put entries in your /etc/hosts file that would link to the websites. If that works then you can be relatively sure that the issue lies with your DNS.

Comment: I have the websites in the host files on the computers and on the server.

Comment: Can users access other resources on the network aside from the websites you're trying to access?

Comment: I am able to use ssh and some of the tools work but others don't. Some of the sites just don't load but there are a few that give a `502 Bad Gateway - Response Error, a bad response was received from another proxy server or the destination origin server.`